# Prove that $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline A\cup \overline B$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that $\overline{A \cup B} = \overline A\cup \overline B$.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 10):

$\bar A\cup \bar B$ is a closed set (because it is the union of two closed sets) and contains $A\cup B$. Hence $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \bar A\cup \bar B$.

On the other hand, $\overline{A\cup B}$ is a closed set  containing $A$, hence $\bar A\subseteq \overline{A\cup B}$. Similarly, $\bar B\subseteq  \overline{A\cup B}$. Hence finally $\bar A\cup \bar B \subseteq \overline{A\cup B}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer why $\overline{A\cup B}\subseteq \bar A\cup \bar B$. Thank You.

Comment: @user93765: the closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing that set.

Comment: @user93765 Why are you pinging Daniel? That's odd. Anyway, as pointed out '$\bar A\cup \bar B$ is a closed set (because it is the union of two closed sets) and contains $A\cup B$'. But since the closure of $A\cup B$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A\cup B$, the inclusion follows.