# Show that $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{A \cup B}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof?

> Show that $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{A \cup B}$.

Clearly,
$$A \cup B \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$
So, $$A \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$
$$B \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$

Since $\overline{A \cup B}$ is closed, we have
$$\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$
$$\overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$
Therefore,
$$\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} \subseteq \overline{A \cup B}$$
Now,
$$A \subseteq \overline{A}$$
$$B \subseteq \overline{B}$$
So,
$$A \cup B \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$

Since $\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$ is closed,
$$\overline{A \cup B} \subseteq \overline{A} \cup \overline{B}$$

Therefore, $$\overline{A} \cup \overline{B} = \overline{A \cup B}$$

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: This question is a duplicate; it was on MSE a few days ago but I can't find it.

Comment: @oliveeuler That may be the case, but I wanted help with my proof in particular, and not the problem in general.

Comment: @EulCan You might mean one of these questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493916/prove-that-overlinea-cup-b-overline-a-cup-overline-b, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891653/prove-that-if-x-is-a-topological-space-and-a-and-b-are-two-subsets-of-x or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812231/closure-of-union-of-two-sets (There are probably several other copies of questions about the same result.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good job on finding those. Out of interest, how did you search for them? Was it just through looking in the topology section?

Comment: @EulCan I think trying to Google something like [closure "A\cup B" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=closure+%22A\cup%20B%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) or [overline "A\cup B" site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=overline+%22A\cup%20B%22+site:math.stackexchange.com) might lead to a few results (which are, in turn, linked to other posts). Perhaps it is also reasonable to try replacing A,B with S,T or X,Y (or even omitting the names of the sets completely).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. It was the symbols that were making it difficult.