# Prove that: If $X$ is a topological space and $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $X$ then,$Cl(A) \cup Cl(B) = Cl(A \cup B) $

Tags: general-topology

Prove that: If $X$ is a topological space and $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of $X$ then,$Cl(A) \cup Cl(B) = Cl(A \cup B) $ where $Cl(H)$ means the closure f the subsets $H $of $X$.

I was able to prove that $Cl(A) \cup Cl(B) \subset Cl(A \cup B) $. I don't know how to prove the other way. The problem is:

If $x\in Cl(A \cup B) $ then every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersect $A \cup B$ so every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects either $A$ or $B$ or both. But it may happen that some neighborhoods intersect $A$ but not $B$ and the rest of them intersect $B$ but not $A$, in which case we get $Cl(A \cup B) \not\subset Cl(A) \cup Cl(B)$. How to proceed?

This problem is from Munkres topology.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493916/prove-that-overlinea-cup-b-overline-a-cup-overline-b and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812231/closure-of-union-of-two-sets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we want to show that $\operatorname{Cl}(A \cup B) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(B)$. There are two ways (at least) to go about this:

Using the definition with neighbourhoods that you use: let $x$ be in $\operatorname{Cl}(A \cup B)$, but suppose $x$ is *not* in $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(B)$. So $x \notin \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ means that there is an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that does not intersect $A$, and $x \notin \operatorname{Cl}(B)$ means that there is an open neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that does not intersect $B$. Then $U \cap V$ is also an open neighbourhood of $x$ and it misses $A$ as the larger $U$ already does, and it misses $B$ because $V$ already does. But then we have an open neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A \cup B$ and this contradicts that $x \in \operatorname{Cl}(A \cup B)$. So we are done.

Using the fact (theorem) that $\operatorname{Cl}(C)$ (for any $C \subset X$) is the *smallest* closed set that has $C$ as a subset: $A \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and $B \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(B)$, so $A \cup B \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(B)$. Now, assuming you have proved that the finite union of closed sets is closed, we conclude that $A \cup B$ is thus contained in the closed set $\operatorname{Cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(B)$. As $\operatorname{Cl}(A \cup B)$ is the smallest such closed set, we know that $\operatorname{Cl}(A \cup B) \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A) \cup \operatorname{Cl}(B)$ and we are done. But this is of course assuming you know that the closure of a set is the smallest subset around that set and closed sets are closed under finite unions.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I wonder, As we proved the inclusion then we KNOW that either such neighborhoods that intersect $A$ but not $B$ or those which intersect $B$ but not $A$, doesn't exist as if both of them existed the inclusion doesn't hold so at least one of them is not there, right? @Henno Brandsma

Comment: If we know that $x$ is in the closure of $A \cup B$, then we know it is either in the closure of $A$ (and every neighbourhood intersects (at least) $A$) or in the closure of $B$ and every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects (at least) $B$. Of course it could always intersect both (and $x$ would even be in the closure of $A \cap B$), or sometimes intersect only one of them. But there is one of the two sets that neighbourhoods of $x$ *always* intersects, yes.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** As $A \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A)$ and $B \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(B)$, $A\cup B \subseteq \operatorname{Cl}(A)\cup\operatorname{Cl}(B)$. Now note that $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\cup\operatorname{Cl}(B)$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

To adress your concern if $U$ intersects $A$ but not $B$ and $O$ intersects $B$  but not $A$ then $U\cap O$ is open and intersects neither.

Comment: In fact, we need every  neighborhood intersect $A$ or every neighborhood intersect $B$ or every neighborhood intersect $A \cup B$ So, your remark doesn't work as $U$ still doesn't intersect $A$ and $O$ doesn't intersect $B$  @Rene Schipperus

Answer (score 1):

A very useful lemma here is the fact that $Cl(A)$ is the minimal closed set containing $A$ (Verify for yourself!).

Assume for the sake of contradiction that the two sets are not equal. We find that, just as Michael said, $Cl(A) \cup Cl(B)$ is closed. In addition, we must have $A \cup B \subset Cl(A) \cup Cl(B)$. Combining this with $Cl(A) \cup Cl(B) \subset Cl(A \cup B)$ gives us the desired result since otherwise we arrive at a contradiction due to the lemma.